# Suggestions for a mashup application

Tags: java, web-applications, mashup

I have to write a mashup application for an university course and I have to use some APIs, but I need to choose by myself what to use and what the final application should do. Unfortunately I never made an application like this, so I'm not sure what to do... I don't want to code a stupid app which uses google maps' APIs since the web seems to be full of stuff like this. Have you got any suggestion for me? Is there any mashup web app you want that's still not there?? I can use JAVA, GWT (and google app engine of course) or python, but I also accept suggestions for other languages.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there's nothing wrong with yet another geo-app, you are right that there are far too many out there.

How do you feel about Social Networking and real-time search? Could you pull out interesting stuff from Twitter, Facebook and the rest then combine it with another source of data.

Mixing it up with stock tickers from Yahoo! Finance would certainly be an interesting portfolio addition for finance industry interviews.

Comment: I don't like social networks too much, but for an application they can be good. The only problem is that it seems that everything that could be do it's already been coded. I'd like to do something new as much as it is possible. Maybe I can do something with lastfm API which are social but related to music... any other idea?
I will also take a look for a finance app...

Comment: There isn't really much new under the sun unfortunately. Really new stuff is obvious once it's written, but almost impossible to figure out beforehand.

This might be a stranger suggestion, but go and track down the Stack Overflow podcast #85 and soak up what Joel and Jeff say about community.

Getting good information out of a social network reliably would be something impressive though. What you consider good is up to you of course. Music, finance, breaking news, celebrity gossip, whatever.

Comment: Yeah I know there isn't much new under the sound, I just want to be as much new as possible. I will listen to the podcast and I will look around at social network + music possibilities. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

YQL has access to several APIs. Perhaps that would make it easier:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Comment: Never heard about YQL, I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

A specific example - Most-Talked-About Tracker

Combine Last.FM, Google News Feeds, Twitter and Google Chart to find out which bands people are talking about, assign scores and show trends. You can compare the media and social coverage to the sales/play data for their music to see if you can predict a one-hit wonder or a lasting band.

If you can, you could add in some text analysis to see if the stuff people are saying is positive or negative. 750words.com has some interesting metrics on it, but I've no idea how it's actually done.

Answer (score 0):

How about a unified photo album? you can retrieve pictures from various sites (facebook, picasa, flicker...) and create an aggregated album per user.

Comment: It's a good idea, but a friend of mine is doing exactly this thing and I can't do the same thing, sorry!